# PostgreSQL SQL statement runs and returns values from pgAdmin 4 v5, statement is run through Flutter/dart db conn it doesn't return anything

Tags: sql, postgresql, flutter, dart

Noob here so apologies if this turns out to be a silly mistake on my part. As I stated I have a SQL statement which runs fine in pgAdmin 4 v5 and runs from within in a python application. I have had a little trouble porting it from python (Didn't remove the string spacers (ooops!). That is all changed and in actual fact for now, to stop there being any variable issues, I have hard coded data into the SQL statement (things like longitude and latitude).

Here is the statement I am trying to use;

```
sqlquery =  """  SELECT name_, address, postcode, latitude, longitude, pubid, monclose,
    monopen, tueopen, tueclose, wedopen, wedclose, thuropen, thurclose, friopen, friclose, satopen,
    satclose, sunopen, sunclose,
    restopenmon, restclosemon, restopentue, restopenwed, restopenthur, restopenfri, restopensat,
    restopensun, restclosetue, restclosewed, restclosethur, restclosefri, restclosesat, restclosesun,
    active, musicbeginmon, musicbegintue,latelogo,
    musicbeginwed, musicbeginthur, musicbeginfri, musicbeginsat, musicbeginsun, musicfinishmon,
    musicfinishtue, musicfinishwed, musicfinishthur, musicfinishfri, musicfinishsat, musicfinishsun,
    ROUND(distance::NUMERIC , 2) distance, case when '23:00:00' >=monclose AND monclose<= '04:00:00' then 1 else 0 end as latenight,
    case when LOCALTIME(0) BETWEEN restopenmon AND restclosemon then 1 else 0 end as food_avail,
    case when LOCALTIME(0) BETWEEN musicbeginmon AND musicfinishmon then 1 end as livemusic,
    case when camra = True then 1 else 0 end as camra
    FROM (
    SELECT z.name_,
    z.address,z.tueopen,
    z.camra, z.monopen,
    z.postcode, z.monclose,
    z.satclose, z.pubid,
    z.latitude, z.longitude,
    z.tueclose, z.wedopen, z.wedclose,
    z.thuropen, z.thurclose, z.friopen,
    z.friclose, z.satopen, z.sunopen, z.sunclose,
    z.restopenmon, z.restclosemon, z.restopentue, z.restopenwed, z.restopenthur,
    z.restopenfri, z.restopensat, z.restopensun, z.restclosetue, z.restclosewed, z.restclosethur,
    z.restclosefri, z.restclosesat, z.restclosesun, z.active, z.musicbeginmon, z.musicbegintue,
    z.musicbeginwed, z.musicbeginthur, z.musicbeginfri, z.musicbeginsat, z.musicbeginsun, z.musicfinishmon,
    z.musicfinishtue, z.musicfinishwed, z.musicfinishthur, z.musicfinishfri, z.musicfinishsat,
    z.musicfinishsun,z.latelogo,
    p.radius,
    p.distance_unit
    * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
    * COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
    * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - z.longitude))
    + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
    * SIN(RADIANS(z.latitude))))) AS distance
    FROM pubs AS z
    JOIN (SELECT 51.1865767 AS latpoint, -0.61877 AS longpoint,
    100 AS radius,      69 AS distance_unit
    ) AS p ON 1=1
    WHERE z.latitude
    BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
    AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
    AND z.longitude
    BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
    AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
    ) AS d
    WHERE distance <= radius AND distance <9
    ORDER BY distance""";
```

When I run this on pgAdmin 4 v5, it returns 243 rows, which is correct but when I try and run this through the db connection it seems to stop half way though the statement, (I was printing out the statement to check it was correctly creating it with the variables in).

The code I am using to connect is

```
var uri = 'postgres://user:password@overthere:5432/db';
var sql = sqlquery;

    print(sql);

await connect(uri).then((conn) {
  conn.query(sql).toList()
      .then((result) {
    print('result: $result');
  });
      //.whenComplete(() {
    conn.close();
  });
}
```

The Statement is printing out as follows to the console;

```
I/flutter ( 5425):   SELECT name_, address, postcode, latitude, longitude, pubid, monclose,
I/flutter ( 5425):     monopen, tueopen, tueclose, wedopen, wedclose, thuropen, thurclose, friopen, friclose, satopen,
I/flutter ( 5425):     satclose, sunopen, sunclose,
I/flutter ( 5425):     restopenmon, restclosemon, restopentue, restopenwed, restopenthur, restopenfri, restopensat,
I/flutter ( 5425):     restopensun, restclosetue, restclosewed, restclosethur, restclosefri, restclosesat, restclosesun,
I/flutter ( 5425):     active, musicbeginmon, musicbegintue,latelogo,
I/flutter ( 5425):     musicbeginwed, musicbeginthur, musicbeginfri, musicbeginsat, musicbeginsun, musicfinishmon,
I/flutter ( 5425):     musicfinishtue, musicfinishwed, musicfinishthur, musicfinishfri, musicfinishsat, musicfinishsun,
I/flutter ( 5425):     ROUND(distance::NUMERIC , 2) distance, case when '23:00:00' >=monclose AND monclose<= '04:00:00' then 1 else 0 end as latenight,
I/flutter ( 5425):     case when LOCALTIME(0) BETWEEN restopenmon AND restclosemon then 1 else 0 end as food_avail,
I/flutter ( 5425):     case when LOCALTIME(0) BETWEEN musicbeginmon AND musicfinishmon then 1 end as livemusic,
I/flutter ( 5425):     case when camra = True then 1 else 0 end as
```

I have not missed or cut anything from this bit above, it just stops with no errors.

I am running PostgreSQL 12, Flutter version 2.0.2 at C:\flutter • Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (4 days ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800 • Engine revision 5d8bf811b3 • Dart version 2.12.1

*Side note:* I know the database is a right mess, it will be rebuilt and changed before use it is literally a dumping server while I figure out what I fully need for my app.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems it was the way I was trying to connect to the database and retrieve the data, I have changed the code to this;

```
final conn = PostgreSQLConnection(normal blah, blah,); 
await conn.open();
     print('connected to database');
     
     List<List<dynamic>> results = await conn.query(sqlquery);
 
     for (final row in results) {
       var a = row[0];
       var b = row[1];
       var c = row[2];
 
      if (results != null) {
        print(a + b + c);
      }
```

now my long SQL query works like a charm, with that data all in the array.